# Finding a solution to a sytem of linear DE's with initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working on a problem:

$$ x' = y - x + t $$
$$ y' = y $$
$$ x(0)=8, y(0)=2 $$

How do I find $x(t)$ and $y(t)$? I'm not even sure where to start.

Comment: Is there a typo in your second equation?

Comment: Fixed. Should be equals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:

$$y' = y, y(0) = 2$$

This is separable, so we can separate and integrate and have:

$$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{dy}{y} = \int dt$$

Can you proceed?

Comment: @Bob: I added details about the first part as a hint. Can you proceed?

Comment: $y=2e^t$. x(t) had to be solved using integration factor after plugging in y. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent and correct! Regards

Comment: Short and sweet! +1

Comment: @amWhy: I like when a slight push allows them to discover the solution! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your second equation contains no $x$ terms, so solve for $y$ straight off. Then plug your answer back in and solve for $x$. Don't forget to take care of your constants!

Comment: I'm not sure how I can solve for y(t) with the given information.